Could not get source code. Error: Off when run file by exe
your textI run source code directly in VCS then no error... But when I package the source code using pyinstaller, it opens and then immediately closes when I run it.. Can you help me, Please..!! This is my first time posting.. I am a newbie and hope to receive some help..
from re import sub
from decimal import Decimal
import inflect
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def convert_to_numbers(money):
    money = money.replace(',', '')
    value = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', money))
    integer_part, decimal_part = int(value), int((value % 1) * 100)
    integer_in_words = p.number_to_words(integer_part).upper().replace(',','')
    decimal_in_words = p.number_to_words(decimal_part).upper().replace(',','')
    return f"SAY TOTAL: U.S. DOLLARS {integer_in_words} AND CENTS {decimal_in_words} ONLY." if decimal_part > 0 else f"SAY TOTAL: U.S. DOLLARS {integer_in_words}."

layout = [
    [sg.Button('CONVERT', button_color=('yellow', 'red'), size=(25, 2), font=('Helvetica', 13))],
    [sg.Text(' ' * 5)], 
    [sg.Text('Paste the number into this box:', size=(25, 1), font=('Helvetica', 13)), sg.Input(key='Digital', size=(150, 3), font=('Helvetica', 13))],
    [sg.Text(' ' * 5)],  
    [sg.Text('Values copy:', size=(25, 1), font=('Helvetica', 13)), sg.Input(key='Text', size=(150, 3), font=('Helvetica', 13))]
]

window = sg.Window('CONVERT MONEY', layout, size=(800, 250), resizable=True, finalize=True)
p = inflect.engine()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'CONVERT' and values['Digital']:
        if not values['Digital'].replace('.', '').replace(',', '').isdigit():
            sg.popup("Please enter a valid number!")
        else:
            result = convert_to_numbers(values['Digital'])
            if result:
                window['Text'].update(result)
            else:
                sg.popup("Please enter a valid number!")

window.close()


Try to run it under console, so you can get exception information for debug, or it will be closed immediately and nothing found !

Add a try around all/most of the program to catch the error and you may be able to then display an error popup that has trackback info.
